# Can't Connect to MongoDB on new Azure VM

Tags: mongodb, azure, docker

I created a new "Container App" in Azure Portal for MongoDB.  This used the official MongoDB container from Docker Hub and created an Ubuntu 15.04 box.  I have never worked with Docker before.

I am able to SSH into the VM and connect to mongo on the VM. From the ssh session, if I type:

> docker ps

I get the following output:

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                      NAMES 
a9af4c2e2b95        mongo               "/entrypoint.sh mongo"   34 minutes ago      Up 24 minutes       0.0.0.0:27017->27017/tcp   compose_mongo_1
```

However, when I try to connect to Mongo from my local box, I get a connection error that says "Failed to connect to ... after 5000 milliseconds, giving up."

At first I thought it was because the port wasn't opened, but I went to the "Network Security Groups" in Azure portal and allowed port inbound TCP traffic on port 27017.

I am still unable to connect. If anyone could help me, I would appreciate it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, A couple of things to keep in mind (and I just tested this end to end, So I am sure it works).

1. Make sure UFW (Ubuntu Firewall also called Uncomplicated Firewall) denies all forwarded traffic by default, so you need to set it to ACCEPT

   sudo nano /etc/default/ufw

Replace

```
DEFAULT_FORWARD_POLICY="DROP"
```

With

```
DEFAULT_FORWARD_POLICY="ACCEPT"
```

and reload the UFW

```
sudo ufw reload
```

2. this is how I run my docker Image

   docker run -p 27017:27017 imageid &
3. Add the endpoint for port 27017 - from your azure portal for this VM (Which you have already done)

this is it, I think you should be all set now...

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  My works firewall won't let me SSH to an outside server right now, but once I get home, I will try editing the firewall.  I will give an update tonight whether it worked or not. Thanks for your help!

Comment: I edited the ufw and ran sudo ufw reload.  I received the following message: Firewall not enabled (skipping reload)
I tried connecting from my computer and the connection still failed.  Any ideas?

Comment: In step 2 you say "docker run -p 27017:27017 &" are you missing something here? What else do you type to run your docker image? I'm new to docker so thanks for being patient with me.

Comment: I wrote ImageID , but in brackets, SOverflow might have thought of it as HTML content and didn't showed it, thanks, its fixed now...

Comment: Do you have to add a new user to the Mongo database or just use the username/password that you entered when you created the VM?

Comment: I'm an idiot! I set the source port in the Network Security Group to 27017. I changed it to * and everything started working. Thanks!